# Port forwarding to podman container not working

Tags: port-forwarding, firewalld, podman

I want to serve port `8000` from a podman container to the LAN using port `8009`.

The container is run using `podman-compose`, which translates to the following command:

```
podman create --name=pihole-unbound_pihole_1 [...] --
net pihole-unbound_default --network-alias pihole -p 53:53/tcp -p 53:53/udp -p 8000:80/tcp --restart unless-stopped pihole-unbound_pihole
```

And I can correctly access my web UI from `http://server.local:8000/`.

I then added the necessary forwarding rules to firewall-cmd like so:

```
firewall-cmd --add-forward-port=port=8009:proto=tcp:toport=8000
```

But accessing it from the outside just times out, e.g.

```
curl -I http://192.168.10.15:8009
```

I've read a lot of guides and posts online about how to forward ports in Fedora/CentOS but almost none specifically talk about the case of containers, except for a few:

- https://tecadmin.net/forwarding-ports-to-docker-containers-using-linux-firewalls/
- https://major.io/p/forwarding-ports-with-firewalld/

But I still can't get it to work. What's more is that I can't even `curl` to the forwarded ports from within the host, but the behavior is different, they just refuse the connection instead of hanging indefinitely:

```
# curl -I http://localhost:8009
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8009 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

I even tried looking into other zones for hints but there seems to be no info about where the rules are.

```
# firewall-cmd --get-zones
FedoraServer FedoraWorkstation block dmz drop external home internal libvirt libvirt-routed nm-shared public trusted work

# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
FedoraServer (default)
  interfaces: enp3s0
trusted
  sources: 10.89.0.0/24 10.89.1.0/24 10.89.2.0/24 10.89.3.0/24

# firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --list-all
trusted (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  ingress-priority: 0
  egress-priority: 0
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: 10.89.0.0/24 10.89.1.0/24 10.89.2.0/24 10.89.3.0/24
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

# firewall-cmd --zone=FedoraServer --list-all
FedoraServer (default, active)
  target: default
  ingress-priority: 0
  egress-priority: 0
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp3s0
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http samba ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
        port=8009:proto=tcp:toport=8000:toaddr=
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Comment: Forwarding rules don't apply to localhost. The forwarded port still needs to be allowed first.

Comment: @AlexD So you say I will never be able to reach the service locally on the forwarded port? Also, I tried allowing it but the result is the same, it just times out...

Comment: Your current port-forwarding rules apply to `enp3s0` interface only. You need to apply port-forwarding for 'lo' separately.

Comment: @AlexD that makes a lot of sense, I will try it and come back with what worked or not